# Akamai Python Login with Nike

Tags: python, json, authentication, cookies, akamai

I have a python script that is to help me log into nike.com I have created everything so far including the sensor data. I'd happily share with someone who can help. However when I am trying to log in I keep getting 403 errors. Even though the sensor data and everything seems flawless and correctly calculated. It mimics everything leading up to logging into the website. It goes to the product page, api, static, sessions.html, and then tried to perform a login.
still 403 error

let me give you a sample of the code itself where I am making the request. This is after 2000 lines of coding:

```
cookies = {
'geoloc': self.geoloc,
'AKA_A2': self.AKA_A2,
'bm_sz': self.bm_sz,
'ak_bmsc': self.ak_bmsc1,
'bm_sv': self.bm_sv2,
'_abck': abck,
'anonymousId': self.anonymousId,
}
headers = {
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'content-length': '170',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'origin': 'https://www.nike.com',
'referer': PRODUCTURL,
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
'user-agent': USER_AGENT,

}

data = {
'client_id': self.CLIENTID,
'grant_type': 'password',
'password:': password,
'username:': username,
'ux_id': 'com.nike.commerce.snkrs.web',
}

params = {
'appVersion': '814',
'experienceVersion': '814',
'uxid': 'com.nike.commerce.snkrs.web',
'locale': 'en_US',
'backendEnvironment': 'identity',
'browser': 'Google%20Inc.',
'os': 'undefined',
'mobile': 'false',
'native': 'false',
'visit': '1',
'visitor': self.xnikevisitorid,
}

response = session.post("https://unite.nike.com/login?", headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data, params=params)
print(abck)
print(response)
print(response.text)
cookies = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies)
print("Session with header Cookies ", response.cookies.keys())
abck = cookies['_abck']
bmsv = cookies['bm_sv']
time.sleep(0.4)
```

This is a sample of the final sensor_data created for the most recent static page before the login page. The static page all give a 201 response. I am not getting any errors anywhere else.

```
7a74G7m23Vrp0o5c9196521.64-1,2,-94,-100,Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36,uaend,12147,20030107,en-US,Gecko,3,0,0,0,393678,9621785,1440,815,1440,900,992,618,992,,cpen:0,i1:0,dm:0,cwen:0,non:1,opc:0,fc:0,sc:0,wrc:1,isc:0,vib:1,bat:1,x11:0,x12:1,8983,0.683910876342,800004810692,0,loc:-1,2,-94,-101,do_en,dm_en,t_en-1,2,-94,-105,-1,2,-94,-102,-1,2,-94,-108,-1,2,-94,-110,0,1,1340,1370,1033;1,1,1362,1164,1813;2,1,1394,1383,1930;3,1,1120,1166,1951;4,1,1081,1144,1990;5,1,1277,1316,2104;6,1,1116,1126,2183;7,1,1318,1099,2343;12,1,1178,1196,3169;13,1,1160,1219,3190;14,1,1208,1157,3249;15,1,1200,1232,3287;16,1,1078,1114,3311;17,1,1218,1286,3366;18,1,1283,1082,3415;20,1,1334,1248,3656;21,1,1350,1115,3771;22,1,1220,1280,3839;23,1,1361,1157,3958;24,1,1307,1198,4020;25,1,1112,1353,4108;26,1,1082,1230,4180;28,1,1291,1267,4213;29,1,1108,1200,4238;30,1,1135,1248,4564;31,1,1342,1365,4590;32,1,1373,1133,4666;33,1,1149,1325,4759;34,1,1232,1075,4907;40,1,1169,1356,5365;41,1,1141,1312,5382;42,1,1162,1277,5565;43,1,1284,1290,5691;44,1,1102,1329,5898;45,1,1227,1159,6022;46,1,1366,1358,6185;-1,2,-94,-117,-1,2,-94,-111,0,584,-1,7.20,-1.10;1,616,-1,8.80,-2.80;2,893,-1,8.70,-1.40;3,1002,-1,3.90,-2.60;4,1025,-1,3.80,-1.80;5,1069,-1,8.30,-2.90;6,1774,-1,2.90,-2.90;7,1844,-1,2.10,-4.70;8,1905,-1,6.40,-8.10;9,2001,-1,4.10,-4.50;2,5077,-1,0.30,-1.40;3,6087,-1,0.70,-9.50;4,6128,-1,0.40,-9.80;5,6662,-1,5.30,-6.90;6,12238,-1,1.50,-2.50;7,12920,-1,9.70,-3.80;8,14641,-1,3.80,-2.50;9,14949,-1,4.30,-6.60;-1,2,-94,-109,0,584,-1,-1,-1,-7.50,-4.50,9.20,-1,-1,-1;1,616,-1,-1,-1,-2.60,-2.40,8.70,-1,-1,-1;2,893,-1,-1,-1,-6.90,-5.10,4.90,-1,-1,-1;3,1002,-1,-1,-1,-1.50,-7.70,9.40,-1,-1,-1;4,1025,-1,-1,-1,-0.90,-6.80,3.90,-1,-1,-1;5,1069,-1,-1,-1,-8.40,-7.60,7.40,-1,-1,-1;6,1774,-1,-1,-1,-6.70,-6.80,6.70,-1,-1,-1;7,1844,-1,-1,-1,-3.80,-2.10,6.30,-1,-1,-1;8,1905,-1,-1,-1,-4.80,-2.30,4.50,-1,-1,-1;9,2001,-1,-1,-1,-8.10,-6.20,4.90,-1,-1,-1;2,5077,-1,-1,-1,-8.30,-4.70,1.50,-1,-1,-1;3,6087,-1,-1,-1,-8.90,-8.80,7.20,-1,-1,-1;4,6128,-1,-1,-1,-0.70,-7.80,5.30,-1,-1,-1;5,6662,-1,-1,-1,-3.50,-2.90,2.30,-1,-1,-1;6,12238,-1,-1,-1,-6.50,-8.10,2.20,-1,-1,-1;7,12920,-1,-1,-1,-7.70,-7.10,1.90,-1,-1,-1;8,14641,-1,-1,-1,-0.70,-2.30,7.80,-1,-1,-1;9,14949,-1,-1,-1,-2.30,-7.50,5.80,-1,-1,-1;-1,2,-94,-114,-1,2,-94,-103,-1,2,-94,-112,https://www.nike.com/launch/t/killshot-og-gorge-green-1,2,-94,-115,1,227268,32,103419,91504,0,422159,7123,0,1600009621384,4,17116,0,10,7123,0,0,7130,8334,0,B365E1BE8738DCC791EF1B57E6EB08BC~-1~YAAQ3KLbF66NJ1J0AQAAKU0BiASuER6aZYo1M/jJirG3p5QqVSngbpiOBV0x+lpj1kPuFFfoGPVClQDVgry7gFIUet1/KOy8rQdp3jqN+0xx/LuFPkAcbaENujOqnC+4iSoEU8XOwFIlj9fJ2XIpMc1XST4Xy7n8ZDOPd9rcbiFYdNZZ36pQUna325824AjnpRwMMLn28zb1ctv7DRaUGDSIVVNX5WEpROhScrhEoWyDhlXtw149DUT/WSu6NSwYEr5zvLZx+UgbVIl36REdZfo2Mydy5STUXPeMAogZJvoDDNRyvrANdjCbzw9BLmDjHvw9ob4CsLgNV/HJSqu8vFPUWA==~-1~||1-ECrOeLGptm-1500-10-1000-2||~-1,34483,380,1600009621384,30261693,PiZtE,32848,61-1,2,-94,-106,3,5-1,2,-94,-119,17,80,56,39,122,63,185,22,48,17,8,13,9,390,-1,2,-94,-122,0,0,0,0,1,0,0-1,2,-94,-123,-1,2,-94,-124,-1,2,-94,-126,-1,2,-94,-127,11321144241322243122-1,2,-94,-70,1008762800;-2011384053;dis;,7,8;true;true;true;240;true;24;24;true;false;-1-1,2,-94,-80,5561-1,2,-94,-116,86596110-1,2,-94,-118,176877-1,2,-94,-129,f80d2f06bb6079f933a24c35bef2005cd2736f91ae877632c8f2d83d3b50eb34,1,122931c7ece5ae8ca5acada410ae9c52cfa6ab41ca356c0324f18cd3a4227682,Google Inc.,Google SwiftShader,76ff9db3820ac1d0e96fcd60f1c52b8062afb79b134e536e04d7e729b855949b,26-1,2,-94,-121,;27;21;0
```

Comment: The issue is with the way you generate your Cookies. Could you update your post to show the actual value of your cookies?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to achieve a similar task. Would you be interested in sharing your knowledge? I can pay you if you manages to bypass Akamai.

Answer (score 2):

Change data = data to json = data in the request.

If that still doesn't work then your sensor data is likely bad.

Also you only need bm_sz and abck_ cookie. You can pre-generate these on the /launch page with a selenium script if need be.

Comment: You mean to launch it using selenium, sign in, and then grab the correct cookies, access token, etc. Then using javascript from that point on basically? I did use json by the way so I guess the cookies are the issue.

Comment: You could do that. However sensor data is likely the problem. You can simply open the nike.com/launch page with selenium and it will give you valid cookies after clicking the login button. You don't need to actually login. Then you can grab the cookies and use them to login with requests.